# Can't use HTTP/3 with CronetTransport in Android

Tags: android, okhttp, http3

I'm trying to implement HTTP/3 with QUIC support in my Android app using OkHttp and [the Cronet transport](https://github.com/google/cronet-transport-for-okhttp/blob/master/README.md). However, all requests are being made under HTTP/2. I have used different devices with different versions. I've tried with Retrofit as well and same result.

The server I'm reaching out does support HTTP3 I've tested it on web and it works fine.

```
private val engine = CronetEngine.Builder(MainActivity.appContext).enableHttpCache(CronetEngine.Builder.HTTP_CACHE_DISK, 10 * 1024 * 1024)
    .build()


    private val callFactory = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(CronetInterceptor.newBuilder(engine).build())
    .build();

private fun getRequest(url: String): JSONObject? {
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()


        val response = callFactory.newCall(request).execute()
        return response.body?.string()?.let { JSONObject(it) }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does it use HTTP/3 if you use the cronet APIs directly?

Comment: I tried that, but still it used HTTP/2. I managed to fix it by enabling QUIC protocol on OkHttp Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like OkHttp does not enable QUIC/HTTP3 by default. So I had to add it manually on its builder.

```
val callFactory =  OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .protocols(listOf(Protocol.QUIC, Protocol.HTTP_2))
   .addInterceptor(CronetInterceptor.newBuilder(engine).build())
   .build();
```

https://github.com/google/cronet-transport-for-okhttp/pull/23